# Как настроить шаринг изображения в социальные сети через ya-share2

Tags: vkontakte-api, share, ya-share2, twitter-api, facebook-graph-api

В наличие есть одностраничный сайт, с которого необходимо отображать ту или иную картинку(картинка выбирается динамически при помощи jquery), которой в дальнейшем можно делиться в соц. сетях(VK, FB, Twitter).

Для ВК:

если я изначально прописываю атрибут data-image="imageUrl", то изображение появляется при репосте. Но когда я формирую этот атрибут динамически, то в адресной строке видно, что изображение не передается и оно подхватывается по-умолчанию(не нужное пользователю).

Для FB:

Добавил в мета тэги страницы несколько записей вида:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://imagePath/image.png" />
```

При шаринге вноdь берется картинка по-умолчанию, а нужно шарить конкретную из списка картинок.

Comment: Единственное решение - подготовить для каждого изображение отдельную страницу.

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что для синглпэйджа такой функционал с шарингом не реализовать?

Comment: Реализовать. Например, можно делиться адресом вида `my.singlepage.app.ru?image-to-share=<image>`. При обработке запроса, соответственно, подставлять в мета-теги соответствующие значения.